# How to converte my IEEE references to ACM references in Latex file?

Tags: acm, ieeeconf

I just changed my whole research paper from IEEE format to ACM format. I am trying to use the same biblo file, but it seems that I have to change the whole reference format. Is there any way I can overcome this issue?

ACM deafult reference file: 
[image]
IEEE reference file:
[image]

Since the output of the pdf generated file will look the same whether it's generated following IEEE/ACM format, can I use a specific package to use the already used IEEE file?

Comment: Do you use BibTeX to create the bibliography? If so, does your document feature a `\bibliographystyle` directive?

Comment: @Mico I am using separate file (xx.bl) with following content : \begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{blogadvertising}  Figueredo, P. \ Blogs and blog advertising. Target Mark 28.3(2005): 37-38.  \end{thebibliography}

Comment: So, basically, you created the `thebibliography` environment by hand and you did *not* use BibTeX -- is this inference correct?

Comment: Please also clarify what you did to "change [the] whole research paper from IEEE format to ACM format". E.g., did you change the argument of `\documentclass`, or did you do more than that?

Comment: @Mico I have changed the documentclass type as same as removing the previous packages and add the new one that works well with acm documentclass.                                 \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flushend}

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and teach yourself the basics of using BibTeX to create a formatted bibliography (instead of creating the bibliography entirely by hand). Be sure to provide the directive `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}` in your LaTeX document, as doing so informs BibTeX that the bibliographic entries should be formatted according to this ACM-based style.

Comment: @Mico I am trying to do so, but when I write in the text \cite{Harvard-01} to cite one record from .bib file I have, it always return (?) instead of linking it. I already mentioned in the main 
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}

Comment: After a LaTeX run, do you then run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?